# Configure gatsby-transformer-remark to add default classes

Tags: gatsby

I am using gatsby with plugins `gatsby-source-filesystem` and `gatsby-transformer-remark` to display markdown files as pages, as described in the [official docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/).

It works great, but I am looking for a way to add default classes to all the elements that are converted from markdown.

Let's say I want each `<h1>` element to have a class of `title`, and `<h2>` elements to have a class of `subtitle` by default.

I managed to do something like this with `gatsby-remark-attr`, but with that I can only add classes programmatically in the markdown file. It looks like this:

```
# My markdown heading
{.title}

## Subtitle
{.subtitle}
```

converts to

```html
<h1 class="title">My markdown heading</h1>
<h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
```

I am looking for a way to define the default classes once for each element and have them applied automatically, without having to specify them in the markdown files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL,DR:** Use [gatsby-remark-default-html-attrs](https://github.com/d4rekanguok/gatsby-remark-default-html-attrs)

---

Gatsby's `gatsby-transformer-remark` use [`mdast-util-to-hast`](https://github.com/syntax-tree/mdast-util-to-hast#hproperties) to convert markdown nodes to html nodes, which then stringified into raw HTML. If the markdown node has a `data.hProperties` object, it'll be converted into html attributes.

Let's say you want to add class name `foo` to all `h1` nodes. You'd need to:

- find the markdown node that'll eventually be transformed into a `h1` html element
- add className to its `data.hProperties`

#### 0. Setup

First, you need a custom plugin to modify markdown nodes of `transformer-remark`. Thankfully, creating a local plugin with gatsby is trivial:

```sh
# Create a `plugins` folder at your root
mkdir plugins
mkdir plugins/remark-default-class-name
cd plugins/remark-default-class-name
npm init -y
touch index.js
```

You'll now get this structure:

```
root
  |--src
  |--gatsby-config.js
  `--plugins
      `--remark-default-class-name
           |--package.json
           `--index.js
```

Then add the new local plugin to `gatsby-config.js`:

```js
// gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
  +       `remark-default-class-name`
        ],
      },
    },
```

---

#### 1. Find the markdown node

The plugin will be given a `markdownAST` object, which allows you to find & modify nodes.

I'd use `unist-util-select` to help finding the right node. It comes with `gatsby-transformer-remark`, but if for some reasons it doesn't work, just install it again.

From here on, it's trivial to find the node:

```js
const { selectAll } = require('unist-util-select');

module.exports = ({ markdownAST }) => {
  // `heading` is equivalent to `h1...h6` in markdown.
  // specify [depth] allow us to target the right heading tag.
  const h1Nodes = selectAll('heading[depth=1]', markdownAST);

  console.log(h1Nodes) 
  // this yields  
  // [{ type: "heading", children: [{ type: "text", value: "..." }] }, ...]
}
```

#### 2. Add className to its data.hProperties

We can modify the node directly.

```js
  const h1Nodes = selectAll('heading[depth=1]', markdownAST);

- console.log(h1Nodes)
  // node doesn't always have data
+ if (!node.data) node.data = {};
+ node.data.hProperties = {
+   className: 'foo'
+ }
```

That's it, all `h1` should have a `foo` class now.

This is a particular interesting question for me, since I'm learning about [Unist](https://github.com/syntax-tree/unist) and its ecosystem, which powers `remark`; so thanks for that.

I make a [simple plugin that's a bit more generic here](https://github.com/d4rekanguok/gatsby-remark-default-html-attrs), feel free to try it out & let me know if something failed.

Comment: Thanks for this well-explained, carefully crafted answer. I also went for creating a plugin, but having looked through yours, mine is far less flexible and more error prone - https://github.com/chrisg86/gatsby-remark-classes . Will definitely give your plugin a try, thanks again.

Comment: Thank you @chrisg86, you actually have already figured it out, so I wasn't so helpful! I think my accidental discovery of the awesome `unist-util-select` is the main thing that makes my implementation more flexible. If I were to stick with `unist-util-visit`, I think I'd do very similar to yours. It was a great question, thank you again for that.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I was modifying a plugin, and trying to look up documentation for the `data.htmlAttributes` property of a node, since in several plugins, I saw [that one being used](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/ca15ef37be3febbacfb830193556048008b2fd58/packages/gatsby-remark-autolink-headers/src/index.js#L58-L62), but I couldn't find _anything_ except [this mention](https://github.com/datapimp/mdast-html#integrations). I now believe this is a (confusing) remnant of code related to older remark/unist versions. Only `data.hProperties` seems to be used in Gatsby v5.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [`gatsby-remark-classes`](https://gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-classes) ([GitHub](https://github.com/chrisg86/gatsby-remark-classes), [NPM](https://npmjs.com/package/gatsby-remark-classes)) which allows you to specify a `classMap` in your `gatsby-config.js`.

```js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
  options: {
    plugins: [
      {
        resolve: `gatsby-remark-classes`,
        options: {
          classMap: {
            "heading[depth=1]": "title",
            "heading[depth=2]": "subtitle",
            paragraph: "para",
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Its functionality seems identical to [`gatsby-remark-default-html-attrs`](https://npmjs.com/package/gatsby-remark-default-html-attrs). Funnily enough, these two plugins were created within one day of each other (Feb 1, 2019 and Feb 2, 2019, respectively).

Comment: the fun fact is explained in the comments of the other solution :)